# Автомaтическая прокрутка слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, setinterval

```js
 var slider = $(".slider"),
  slides = slider.find('li'),
  nav = slider.find('nav');

 slides.eq(0).addClass('current');

 nav.children('a').eq(0).addClass('current_dot');

function set (event) {
  
  $(this).addClass('current_dot').siblings().removeClass('current_dot');
  slides.eq($(this).index()).addClass('current').removeClass('prev').siblings().removeClass('current');
  slides.eq($(this).index()).prevAll().addClass('prev');
  slides.eq($(this).index()).nextAll().removeClass('prev');
  
 };
  setInterval(set, 2000);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic);
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
html {
 font-size: calc(5px + 0.4vw);
}
body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.intro {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}
.left {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: 60%;
 padding: 3rem 3rem 3rem 5rem;
 display: table;
}
.left > div {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
span {
  color: #E8CA2B;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 8rem;
 margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
h1 + p {
  color: #949494;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
p + a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #000;
}
.slider {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.slider li {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 transition: clip .7s ease-in-out, z-index 0s .7s;
 clip: rect(0, 100vw, 100vh, 100vw);
 display: table;
}
.center-y {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 5rem;
 font-style: italic;
}
h3 + a {
 font-size: 1.6rem;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 2rem;
}
h3, h3 + a {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .7s 0s, transform .5s .2s;
 transform: translate3d(0, 50%, 0);
}
li.current h3, li.current h3 + a {
 opacity: 1;
 transition-delay: 1s;
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
li.current {
 z-index: 1;
 clip: rect(0, 100vw, 100vh, 0);
}
li.prev {
 clip: rect(0, 0, 100vh, 0);
}
.slider nav {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 5%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 10;
}
nav a {
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 1.2rem;
 height: 1.2rem;
  min-width: 12px;
  min-height: 12px;
 background: #fff;
 margin: 0 1rem;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
a.current_dot {
 transform: scale(1.4);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 .left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
 }
 .slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<section class="intro">


      <div class="slider">
        <ul>
         <li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477281765962-ef34e8bb0967?auto=format&fit=crop&w=3032&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>Что такое IT-конференция?</h3>
              <a href="#">Перейти на сайт</a> 
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454165205744-3b78555e5572?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>IT-конференция-новый взгляд на привычные вещи</h3>
              <a href="#">Перейти на сайт</a> 
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484914440268-8d352fe4db95?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>Мастер классы от выдающихся людей,у которых есть чему учиться</h3>
              <a href="#">View Project</a> 
            </div>
          </li>

          
<li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496902526517-c0f2cb8fdb6a?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>Прямое взаимодействие с потенциальным работодателем</h3>
              <a href="#">View Project</a> 
            </div>
          </li>
          
          <li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496469888073-80de7e952517?auto=format&fit=crop&w=2089&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>встреча выпускников</h3>
              <a href="#">View Project</a> 
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475483768296-6163e08872a1?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>Приятный вечер с разговорами и гитарой</h3>
              <a href="#">View Project</a> 
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
          <nav>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </nav>
        </ul>
      </div>
 </section>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Вопрос как и справить что бы прокрутила до последнего и остановилась?

Comment: у вас там какой-то GoogleMaps с ошибкой выпадает, оно тут к чему вообще?

Comment: в общем чтобы остановилось, надо при запуске интервалов сохранить хэндл, и когда в обработчике дойдете до последнего элемента, остановить выполнение интервальной функции. вообще по факту у меня они по кругу и не крутятся

Comment: @teran, а не подскажите по какой причине слайдер прокручивает с первой сразу на последнюю?

Comment: начните с того, что `this` в контексте функции это не текущий слайд, а `window`

Answer (score 1):

видимо вы что-то такое сделать хотели?

повторю замечания из комментариев, что для остановки *слайд-шоу* запомните хэндл возвращаемый `setInterval`, и остановие его с помощью `clearInterval()`.
А что касается самой функции, то у вас там используется `$(this)`. Вероятно раньше функция висела на клике на сами `li`-слайдера. Конечно, в контексте интервальной функции `$(this)` уже не указывает на слайды, а кажет на объект `window`.

```js
var slider = $(".slider");

var sdata = { 
     slides: slider.find('li'), 
     current: slider.find('li').eq(0),
     count: slider.find('li').length,
     siHandle : null,
     nav : slider.find('nav')
     
};


function set (event) {  
    if(!sdata.count--){
        clearTimeout(sdata.siHandle);
        return;
    }
    var c = sdata.current.next();
    
    c.addClass('current')
     .siblings()
        .removeClass('current');
    c.prevAll().addClass('prev')     ;
    c.nextAll().addClass('next');
    
    sdata.current = c;    
    sdata.nav.find('.current_dot')
       .removeClass('current_dot')
       .next()
         .addClass('current_dot')
       
};
  
sdata.siHandle = setInterval(set, 2000);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic);
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
html {
 font-size: calc(5px + 0.4vw);
}
body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.intro {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}
.left {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: 60%;
 padding: 3rem 3rem 3rem 5rem;
 display: table;
}
.left > div {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
span {
  color: #E8CA2B;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 8rem;
 margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
h1 + p {
  color: #949494;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
p + a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #000;
}
.slider {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.slider li {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 transition: clip .7s ease-in-out, z-index 0s .7s;
 clip: rect(0, 100vw, 100vh, 100vw);
 display: table;
}
.center-y {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 5rem;
 font-style: italic;
}
h3 + a {
 font-size: 1.6rem;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 2rem;
}
h3, h3 + a {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .7s 0s, transform .5s .2s;
 transform: translate3d(0, 50%, 0);
}
li.current h3, li.current h3 + a {
 opacity: 1;
 transition-delay: 1s;
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
li.current {
 z-index: 1;
 clip: rect(0, 100vw, 100vh, 0);
}
li.prev {
 clip: rect(0, 0, 100vh, 0);
}
.slider nav {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 5%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 10;
}
nav a {
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 1.2rem;
 height: 1.2rem;
  min-width: 12px;
  min-height: 12px;
 background: #fff;
 margin: 0 1rem;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
a.current_dot {
 transform: scale(1.4);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 .left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
 }
 .slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<section class="intro">


      <div class="slider">
        <ul>
         <li class="current" style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477281765962-ef34e8bb0967?auto=format&fit=crop&w=3032&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>Что такое IT-конференция?</h3>
              <a href="#">Перейти на сайт</a> 
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454165205744-3b78555e5572?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>IT-конференция-новый взгляд на привычные вещи</h3>
              <a href="#">Перейти на сайт</a> 
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484914440268-8d352fe4db95?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>Мастер классы от выдающихся людей,у которых есть чему учиться</h3>
              <a href="#">View Project</a> 
            </div>
          </li>

          
<li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496902526517-c0f2cb8fdb6a?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>Прямое взаимодействие с потенциальным работодателем</h3>
              <a href="#">View Project</a> 
            </div>
          </li>
          
          <li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496469888073-80de7e952517?auto=format&fit=crop&w=2089&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>встреча выпускников</h3>
              <a href="#">View Project</a> 
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475483768296-6163e08872a1?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D)">
            <div class="center-y">
              <h3>Приятный вечер с разговорами и гитарой</h3>
              <a href="#">View Project</a> 
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
          <nav>
            <a href="#" class="current_dot"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </nav>
        </ul>
      </div>
 </section>


</body>
</html>
```